# Read n integers / float / string from standard input

Tags: go

Algorithm competition have questions that provide the input in multiple lines, with the first line specifying the count of the inputs. Example -

```
3
78
42
99
```

The first line tells that there will be 3 integers followed by the three integers.

Currently, I have the following code to read them -

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var num []int
    var input int
    var count int

    fmt.Scanf("%d", &count)

    for {
       if (count == 0) {
           break
       }

       fmt.Scanf("%d", &input)
       num = append(num, input)

       count--
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to carry this out? The above approach feels clumsy for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

This code pushes everything into the loop header, as well as puts `input` into the most local scope possible. You should be checking the error returned by Scanf too:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var num []int
    var count int
    var err error

   for _, err = fmt.Scanf("%d\n", &count); err == nil && count > 0; count-- {
       var input int
       _, err = fmt.Scanf("%d\n", &input)
       num = append(num, input)
   }

   if err != nil {
       panic(err)
   }

}
```

There are about a million ways to write equivalent code, this seemed the best to me. An argument could be made for putting the error check in the loop before the `append`, but since encountering an error presumably invalidates the list, I thought it looked prettier this way.

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "os"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

    a:= read(reader,100000)

    fmt.Println(a)
}

func read (reader *bufio.Reader, n int)([]uint32) {

    a := make([]uint32, n)
    for i:=0; i<n; i++ {
        fmt.Fscan(reader, &a[i])
    }

    return a
}
```